# Unsure why function using $(this) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function entitled `changeSize()` which i want to change the size of the div / span etc that it is used next to. Here is my code:

```
function changeSize(width, height) {
    $(this).css('height', height);
    $(this).css('width', width);
}

$('#square').changeSize(200, 200);
```

I presumed that the changeSize would replace (this) with `('#square')` because it is used next to the function - but it doesn't

Comment: `changeSize` is just a function and has nothing to do with a jquery object

Comment: "next to the function"? $(this) depends on the event scope

Comment: functions and methods don't work that way.  It could work that way if you called it like this: `changeSize.call($('#square').get(0), 200, 200);`, but you should just extend jQuery. https://jsfiddle.net/obwLj7kq/

Answer (score 4):

Your `changeSize` function is not a method on the jQuery object. You would need to pass the element as a parameter.

```
function changeSize(element, width, height) {
  element.css('height', height);
  element.css('width', width);
}

changeSize($('#square'), 200, 200);
```

Comment: If `changeSize` is called from an event listener, `$(this)` is applicable to the element that called the event.

Comment: @SterlingArcher of course, but OP didn't mention anything about triggering on an event